# Qt does not detect Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, qt, android-ndk, android-sdk-tools

I want to develop Android apps with Qt. I have Extracted the Android SDK and NDK to `C:\`. This is the NDK I downloaded:

> https://squeak-android-vm.googlecode.com/files/android-ndk-1.6_r1-windows.zip

But Qt 5.2.1 does not detect the NDK and this error is shown:

> "C:\android-ndk-1.6_r1" does not seem to be an Android NDK top folder.

Do I downloaded a wrong NDK? Did I miss something?

Thanks

Comment: Nejat: Thanks for your edit so much. I really have a good feeling about you. Don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I strongly recommend to install the latest version of Qt for Android (5.4.1 at present). Also you should download and install Android SDK (ver. 22+) and NDK (ver. r9+) from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

After downloading extract them. For Android SDK you should have a connection to Internet and download the desired tools. you have to install at least Android API-13! You should also install Android SDK Platform-tools and Android SDK Build-tools.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The problem was I first created a Android NDK folder to extract the Android NDK files into it. The extraction procession then created a sub folder of the same name. To solve the problem, I moved the sub folder one directory level up and deleted the initial Android NDK folder I first created.